# How to stop Camera capture in as3, flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm starting work on flex using flashbuilder and I was testing cameras. Now I can get a camera to display but when I try using the stop button to stop the camera from capturing, ti doesn't work this is what I tried.

```
    var video:Video;
    public function startCamera(muteCam:Boolean=false):void{
        video = new Video(); // this will work after the import is done

        var camera:Camera=Camera.getCamera();
        if(muteCam){
        video.attachCamera(camera);

        vidHolder.addChild(video);
        }else{
            video.attachCamera(null);
            if(contains(video))
            vidHolder.removeChild(video);
            //camera=null;

        }


    }
```

These are my components

```
<s:Button x="116" y="28" label="Start" click="startCamera(true)"/>
    <s:VideoDisplay id="vidHolder" x="31" y="87" width="200" height="300"
                    />
    <s:Button id="stop" x="208" y="28" label="Stop" click="startCamera(false)"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new Video object every single time you call `startCamera`. So you are trying to remove a video which isn't actually on the stage.

Instead of:

```
video = new Video();
```

Use this:

```
if ( !video ) {
    video = new Video();
}
```

That will only create the Video object if it has not already been created (`!object` evaluates the object to see if it is null or a boolean set to false. `object == null` would evaluate the same way in this case)